# how to radcombobox passing value id from database

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I am using Telerik controls on my aspx page. I have 3 of them on my page. the values of 2nd and the 3rd rad combo box depends selection on the 1st.The values are coming from a database where the values of 2nd and the 3rd dropdown based on ID the 1st..

**for example**

> ddl 1st will be appear tag name => on database id=1 tag name => on
>   database id=2
>
> ddl 2nd,3rd will be appear based on id from ddl 1st...

anyone can help me,please ?

Comment: anyone help me please ?? I don't know to fix it ??

Comment: Can you please provide your code?

Comment: this if 1st ddl selected...
`protected void RadFilType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, RadComboBoxSelectedIndexChangedEventArgs e)
    {
            RadDatAgg.DataSource = Facade.Monitoring.SelectDataAggregation(UserProfile.UserLogin,hdnParameterID.Value).Tables[0];
            RadDatAgg.DataValueField = "AggregationTypeName";
            RadDatAgg.DataTextField = "AggregationTypeName";
            RadDatAgg.DataBind();
    } `

and else I can't do again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/functionality/multiplecomboboxes/defaultcs.aspx. Use the SelectedIndexChanged event to provide a new datasource to the relevant combo in the code-behind.